# Error while trying to read file in Data Lake storage

Tags: azure, acl, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

In my Azure Data Lake Store I seek to read a file that I imported using a pipeline in Azure Data Factory 2.

Although I am logged in with the same credentials that I used to create the Data Factory, the App Registration for the Data Factory, and the Data Lake itself, I get the following error message:

> ERROR: AccessControlException
>
> MESSAGE: OPEN failed with error 0x83090aa2 (Forbidden. ACL verification failed. Either the resource does not exist or the user is not authorized to perform the requested operation.). [1a8ca11b-d726-468a-9aeb-d8ef3d93a81d] failed with error 0x83090aa2 (Forbidden. ACL verification failed. Either the resource does not exist or the user is not authorized to perform the requested operation.). [1a8ca11b-d726-468a-9aeb-d8ef3d93a81d][2018-06-19T07:45:23.8686252-07:00]

My first thought was, this has obviously something to do with access permissions. So just out of curiousity I gave Read, Write and Execute access to 'Everyone else' in the Access page of the folder holding my file. Interestingly enough, the same error occurs.

Why?

The IR I use was autoselected during creation and is called 'AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime'.

Comment: what is your destination data store? Are you using a selfhosted IR?

Comment: @FangLiu thank you for the comment. I added information about the IR. What do you mean by 'destination data store'?

Comment: Are you using copy activity? If yes, then you want to copy file from Azure data lake to where?

Comment: I used a copy task, yes. I copied the file from a SQL Server to the Azure Data Lake.

Comment: Is the sql server associated with a selfhosted IR? If yes, then you need allow the IP of the machine hosting the selfhosted IR access your ADLS.

Answer (score 0):

Please also check your fire wall settings.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-secure-data (Set IP address range for data access)

Enabled fairwall and Allow access to Azure service "ON"

You also need allow the IP of your selfhosted IR machine access your ADLS because the copy will happen on your selfhosted IR.